# Regex: Add space if letter is adjacent to a number

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP and not really good with regex. I need a preg_replace that can add a space if a letter or number is adjacent.

These are the scenarios:

```
mystreet12 -> mystreet 12
mystreet 38B -> mystreet 38 B
mystreet16c -> mystreet 16 c
my street8 -> my street 8
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You could use lookarounds to match such positions like so:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/i', ' ', $str);
```

Depending on how you define "letter" you may want to adjust `[a-z]`.

Lookarounds are required to make it work properly with strings like:

```
0a1b2c3
```

Where solutions without would fail.

Comment: Doesn't work if the number adjacent to the character is negative.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharyya are there negative street numbers? If you want that feature it's trivial to add the `-` where it's needed. Just replace all the `\d`s with `[-\d]`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
preg_replace("/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/i","\\1 \\2", $subject);
```

Should get you far :)

Answer (score 2):

Using POSIX classes for portability:

```
preg_replace("/([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]])/", "\\1 \\2", $subject);
```

gets the the first transition.

```
preg_replace("/([[:digit:]])([[:alpha:]])/", "\\1 \\2", $subject);
```

gets the second.