# Laravel query adding spaces between inputs for car license plate

Tags: laravel, input

How do I add spaces to input in the data?

Example:

```
$request->PoliceNo= B123A
```

Must be in database = `B 123 A`

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_replace.
stated at [Regex: Add space if letter is adjacent to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024261/regex-add-space-if-letter-is-adjacent-to-a-number)

```
$test= 'B123A';
$request->PoliceNo= preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/i', ' ', $test);
```

Comment: May I know what does <= mean in the reg ex?